# How to efficiently deserialize nvp dictionary from std::string using boost

Tags: dictionary, boost

Suppose I have a stringified representation of a name-value-pair dictionary with custom separators between names/values and name-value pairs, e.g. "foo:4|bar:-1" or "Alice=>cat;Bob=>dog".
It can be done with boost's split(), but I was curious if firstly, doing so isn't just reinventing the wheel, secondly, there are more efficient alternatives, like some customized deserialization.

Comment: Boost Property Tree has some formats that you might like. Obviously, you might not require the hierarchical features: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/property_tree.html

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Boost Spirit. Using the X3 version you'd write

```
const std::string input = "foo:4|bar:-1"; // or "Alice=>cat;Bob=>dog";

auto text = +~x3::char_(":|");

std::map<std::string, int> parsed;
if (parse(input.begin(), input.end(), (text >> ':' >> x3::int_) % '|', parsed)) {
    std::cout << "parsed[bar]: " << parsed["bar"]  << "\n";
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c05ae40aee8c46d1)</kbd>**

---

The other form:

```
const std::string input = "Alice=>cat;Bob=>dog";

auto text = +(x3::char_ - ';' - "=>");

std::map<std::string, std::string> parsed;
if (parse(input.begin(), input.end(), (text >> "=>" >> text) % ';', parsed)) {
    std::cout << "parsed[Bob]: " << parsed["Bob"]  << "\n";
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b549daf15940cd3e)</kbd>**

Comment: Great! I'll try that and Boost.Property too. BTW, I was hoping you'd be one of the answerers, your fame preceeds you:)